# Can't uninstall "Translation Language capabilities (tmgmt_language_combination)" dissabled ALL translation modules that might be dependant

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, debugging

I've tried drush, I disabled i18, ALL fields, multilingual, entity translation, l10n, everything about translation is disabled.

How can I completely get rid of this module, it's caused nothing but griefwith patches and bugs...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had to go into Phpmyadmin browse system>> search tmgmt_language_combination

Click on edit and set status to 0

Then I had to manually delete the modules, refresh, repaste the modules, then refresh, and finally it showed up as red.